# ElasticSearch: which way is better If I only want to return some fields？

Tags: elasticsearch

I only want to return some fields(for example: **price** and **page**) from a index **book** in elasticsearch, which of the following two methods is better? Any comments are welcome  .

1st way:

```java
searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource(false);
searchSourceBuilder.docValueField("price");
searchSourceBuilder.docValueField("page");
```

2nd way:

```java
String[] includesField = {"price","page"};
searchSourceBuilder.fetchSource(includesField,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option will give you the doc values of the fields, i.e. the actual tokens that have been analyzed and indexed.

The second option will return you the exact values as you can see them in the source document.

So both approaches are correct. For numerical values, either approach works. For textual values, it just depends on what you actually want to see.

Comment: thanks,your answer is very enlightening. In this question ,“price” and “page” are all numerical values.Under this premise ,can i say the first option will performs better ?

Comment: Yes, the first option will perform better because ES won't need to retrieve the whole source document and parse the two fields out of it.